# How to prove that $k^3+3k^2+2k$ is always divisible by $3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, divisibility

How can I prove that the following polynomial expression is divisible by 3 for all integers $k$?

$$k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k$$

Comment: It is always divisible by 2, too. So it is always divisible by 6.

Comment: Can someone make the title equation match the question equation?  :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Rewrite $k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k = k(k+1)(k+2)$. Since exactly one of the three factors must be divisible by 3, the product must also.

Answer (score 20):

HINT: Try factoring!

Another hint:

> $$k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k = k(k^2 + 3k + 2) =  k (k+1)(k+2) $$
> Thus, you expression is the product of *three* consecutive integers.

Answer (score 17):

To check if values $p(k)$ of the polynomial $p$ with integer coefficients is divisible by $m$ for all integer $n$, you only to check that
$$p(k) \equiv 0 \pmod m, \; \forall  k \in {0,\ldots,n-1}\tag{1}$$
or equivalently
$$m \mid p(k),  \; \forall  k \in {0,\ldots,n-1}$$

So if $p(k)=k^3+3k^2+2k$ we have

- $p(0)=0$ is divisible by $3$
- $p(1)=6$ is divisible by $3$
- $p(2)=24$ is divisible by $3$

and therefore $p(k)$ is divisible by $3$ for every integer $k$.

I think using $(1)$ is less elegant than the solution that factors the polynomial $p(k)$ but it shows a statement about the infinite set of integers that can be divided in finitely many cases that can be checked by a computer program.

Comment: I second that.  Being clever is great, but it is also very useful to know how one can solve a problem if one does not have a clever idea.

Comment: this approach holds even (_especially_) in situations when factoring comes up short

Comment: +1 for this. It's exactly as Carsten S says--this is actually a much more general approach, and generality is more important than elegance!

Answer (score 14):

If $k$ is a multiple of $3$, then the statement is obviously true. Then suppose that $k$ is not a multiple of $3$. Since $k$ and $3$ are coprime,
\begin{equation}
k^2 \equiv 1\pmod 3
\end{equation}
by Euler's theorem. Then
\begin{equation}
k^3+3k^2+2k \equiv 3k\equiv 0. \pmod 3
\end{equation}
Therefore $k^3+3k^2+2k$ is divisible by $3$.

Comment: Euler's theorem seems a bit overkill for the statement that modulo 3, $(\pm 1)^2 = 1$ ;-)

Comment: If Euler's theorem did not come immediately to mind, you could note the quadratic term falls out since it has coefficient 3, and the two remaining are negative of each other mod 3 by Fermat's little theorem.

Comment: If Euler's theorem did come to mind, the Fermat's Little Theorem *also* came to mind, and we have 3k^2 + 3k = 0 mod 3.

Answer (score 8):

Write the polynomial this way:
\begin{align*}
k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k
&= (k^3 -3k^2 + 2k) + 6k^2 \\
&= k(k-1)(k-2) + 6k(k-1) + 6k \\
&= 6 \binom{k}{3} - 12 \binom{k}{2} + 6\binom{k}{1}
\end{align*}
But then it follows immediately that
$$
k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k = 6 \left[ \binom{k}{3} - 2 \binom{k}{2} + \binom{k}{1} \right]
$$
is divisible by $6$, and in particular divisible by $3$.

---

This isn't just a cute trick. It is actually a much more general approach that will solve all such problems.

The standard way of writing polynomials is in the basis
$$
1, x, x^2, x^3, \ldots
$$
While this generally works fine, many discrete problems about polynomials (especially those about divisibility or integer-valued polynomials) are more natural when you use the following discrete basis of polynomials:
$$
1, \binom{x}{1}, \binom{x}{2}, \binom{x}{3}, \ldots
$$
We have the following results:

**Theorem 1.** Every polynomial with rational coefficients, say $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, can be written uniquely as a finite linear combination (with rational coefficients) of the polynomials $\left\{\binom{x}{i} \right\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$.

**Theorem 2.** For $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$, $p(n)$ is an integer for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ *if and only if* when it is written as a linear combination of the basis $\left\{\binom{x}{i} \right\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$, all coefficients are integers.
(See [integer-valued polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer-valued_polynomial).)

An immediate corollary to Theorem 2 is that a polyomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients is always divisible by $m$ if and only if when you write it in the $\binom{x}{i}$ basis, all of the coefficients are divisible by $m$. Hence, by a simple change-of-basis you can easily decide not just if $x^3 + 3x^2 + 2x$ is always divisible by $3$, but if any polynomial is always divisible by any integer. It's just a matter of writing it in a different basis than you are given.

---

*Proof of Theorem 2.*
Since $\binom{n}{i}$ is always an integer for integer $n$ and $i$,
the backward direction is clear.
For the forward direction, consider a polynomial $p(x)$ with rational coefficients that maps integers to integers.
Then apply Theorem 1 to obtain
$$
p(x) = a_0 \binom{x}{0} + a_1 \binom{x}{1} + \cdots + a_k \binom{x}{k}.
$$
Suppose towards contradiction that not all $a_i$ are integers.
Then consider the first $i$ such that $a_{i}$ is not an integer.
Since $\binom{i}{j} = 0$ for $j > i$, we have
$$
p(i) =
\underbrace{\underbrace{a_0 \binom{i}{0} + a_1 \binom{i}{1} + \cdots + a_{i-1} \binom{i}{i-1}}_{\in \mathbb{Z}}
+ a_i \binom{i}{i}}_{\in \mathbb{Z}} + 0
$$
implying that $a_i \binom{i}{i} \in \mathbb{Z}$.
But $\binom{i}{i} = 1$, so $a_i \in \mathbb{Z}$, contradiction.

Comment: I don't understand your proof of theorem 2, what if $i < k$? How then can you say that $p(i)$ is equal to that sum without the terms beyond $a_i$?

Comment: @Brennan.Tobias I added a little clarification. The terms after $a_i \binom{i}{i}$ are all zero.

Comment: Thanks, That's a really elegant proof!

Comment: This is a textbook example of a *really* good answer saving a ... not good question.

Comment: @pjs36 Well, yes. The question is bad. But it is kind of fun to see all the different answers.

Comment: @6005 Yes, absolutely! I was worried my comment wasn't very clear. I'm kind of perversely happy the question wound up getting attention, due to this answer in particular.

Comment: @pjs36 Thanks :)

Comment: A bit complicated process

Comment: @saisaandeep Complicated to understand, maybe, but far more general. In fact, you could write a computer program to do it for you and then never worry about it again.

Answer (score 7):

Yet another approach: simply plugging in values gives

$$ 0^3 = 0 \mod 3 $$
$$ 1^3 = 1 \mod 3 $$
$$ 2^3 = 2 \mod 3 $$

In other words, $ k^3 = k \mod 3 $.

Therefore, $ k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k = 3k^2 + 3k = 0 \mod 3 $

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, consider induction. The base case is clear. Assuming it holds for some $k$, $(k+1)^3+3 (k+1)^2+2 (k+1) = 3(k+2) (k+1) + (k^3+3 k^2+2 k)$ and so it holds for $k+1$.

Answer (score 5):

Just to be different.  If $k \in \mathbb Z$ then $k = 3m + i$ where $i = $ either $0, 1,$ or $-1$ and $m \in \mathbb Z$.
So
\begin{align*}
k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k
&=(3m + i)^3 + 2(3m + i)+ 3k^2 \\
&= 3^3m^3 + 3 \cdot 3^2m^2 \cdot i + 3 \cdot 3m \cdot i^2 + i^3 + 2 \cdot 3m + 2i + 3k^2 \\
&= i^3 + 2i + 3\big[3^2m^3 + 3^2m^2i + 3m \cdot i^2 + k^2\big]
\end{align*}

Now $i^3 = i$ for $i = 0,1,-1$ so $i^3 + 2i = 3i$.
So
$$
k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k = 3\big[i + 3^2m^3 + 3^2m^2i + 3m \cdot i^2 + k^2\big].
$$

...

But seriously, factoring is the better way to do it.

Comment: Isn't a bit confusing and unnecessary to use $i$ for something that not the imaginary number $i$?

Comment: @snoram not in an obviously-not-complex domain like this. See how many times $i$ crops up with a meaning other than $\sqrt {-1}$ [on the wikipedia page about summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation), for example

Comment: @AakashM: The people that edit Wikipedia use it $\Rightarrow$ it is not unnecessary and confusing?

Comment: @snoram I'm not asserting that. I'm saying that using $i$ for things other than $sqrt {-1}$ is completely standard practice, and is generally not found to be confusing. I've no idea what is or isn't 'unnecessary'.

Comment: I think stating "where $i = 0,1 , -1$" has to rule out any confusion.  But even so  $i$ is perhaps the must common indexing variable.Confusion is a minimal concern.  Even $\pi$ is "overloaded"  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  Personally I prefer to use $k$ for a "plus a constant" value as this is but $k$ was already in use. It never occurred to me it'd look like $i$ and had I, I might have considered $j$ but I don't think it can be considered a serious concern.  No more than a treatise on carnivorous birds should be concerned about the religion symbolism of owls.

Answer (score 5):

Avoiding the factoring solution (since that's a special case - elegant, but not general):

We can ignore the $3k^2$ in $k^3+3k^2+2k$, so we just want to know if $k^3+2k=k(k^2+2)$ is divisible by $3$.  Either $k$ is divisible by $3$, or it is not, in which case 
$k^2 \equiv 1 \mod 3$

Then $k^2+2\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

Answer (score 2):

By [Fermat's Little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) $k^3\equiv k\pmod{3}$, therefore:

$$k^3+\underbrace{3k^2}_{\equiv 0}+\underbrace{2k}_{\equiv -k}\equiv k^3-k\equiv 0\pmod{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

Factorise $k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k = k(k+1)(k+2)$. 
Let $k\equiv 2 \mod 3$.
Then $k+1\equiv 0 \mod 3$
and $k+2\equiv 1 \mod 3$.
So, $k(k+1)(k+2)\equiv 0*1*2 \mod 3$.
Therefore $k(k+1)(k+2)\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

Comment: This can also be done by taking either $k\equiv 1 \mod 3$ Or $k\equiv 0 \mod 3$.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we had to choose $3$ things out of $k+2$ things, there are $k+2$ ways of choosing the first one, $k+1$ ways of choosing the next, and $k$ ways of choosing the third. But we've overcounted by a factor of six, because any three things could be chosen in six different orders. So

$$(k+2)(k+1)k=k^3+3k^2+2k$$

divides by six and hence also by three.

Answer (score 0):

Even integer $k$ can be written as $3l+m$, $m\in\{0,1,2\}$. We can progressively eliminate the obvious: for instance $3k^2$. Remains $(3l+m)^3$ and $2(3l+m)$. Developping the first term, only $m^3$ remains. In the second term, only $2m$ remains. So we are left with $m^3+2m = m^3-m+(2m+m)$. Remains $m^3-m = m(m-1)(m+1)$, which are consecutive integers. So one of them is a multiple of $3$.

Some converse and related techniques are the [Proof by infinite descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_infinite_descent) or [Vieta jumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta_jumping). Or an adaptation of Sherlock Holmes "when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth"; here we have: "when you have eliminated the obvious, whatever remains, however simple, must be trivial".

Answer (score 0):

Without noticing that the expression is factorisable into 3 consecutive numbers:

Define $a = k \;\text{mod}\;3$

$$(k^3 + 3k^2 + 2k) \;\text{mod}\;3 \\
= (k^3\;\text{mod}\;3 + 3k^2\;\text{mod}\;3 + 2k\;\text{mod}\;3) \;\text{mod}\;3 \\
= (a^3\;\text{mod}\;3 + 3a^2\;\text{mod}\;3 + 2a\;\text{mod}\;3) \;\text{mod}\;3$$

### $a^3 \;\text{mod}\;3$:

1. If $a=1$, $a^3 = 1$.
2. If $a=2$, $a^3\;\text{mod}\;3=8\;\text{mod}\;3=2$.

So $a^3 \;\text{mod}\;3 = a$.

## $3a^2\;\text{mod}\;3 = 0$

## $2a\;\text{mod}\;3$:

1. If $a=1$, $2a\;\text{mod}\;3 = 2$.
2. If $a=2$, $2a\;\text{mod}\;3 = 4\;\text{mod}\;3 = 1$.

So $2a \;\text{mod}\;3 = -a\;\text{mod}\;3$.

$$(a + 0 + -a)\;\text{mod}\;3 = 0$$.