# The condition that given polynomial is divisible by 3

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

In [How to prove that $k^3+3k^2+2k$ is always divisible by $3$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639720/how-can-i-prove-that-the-following-is-divisible-by-3), I showed $k^3+3k^2+2k$ is divisible by $3$ using Euler's theorem, specifically, Fermat's little theorem. Then I thought that it is possible to find condition that given polynomial with integer coefficient is divisible by $3$.

---

**First attempt:**

Let $k$ be an integer not divisible by 3. By Fermat's little theorem,
\begin{equation}
k^2\equiv 1.\pmod 3
\end{equation}
In general,
\begin{equation}
k^{2n}\equiv (k^2)^n \equiv 1^n \equiv 1\pmod 3
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
k^{2n+1}\equiv (k^{2n}) k\equiv k\pmod 3
\end{equation}
When $a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{2n-1} k^{2n-1}$ is given,
\begin{equation}
a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{2n-1} k^{2n-1} \equiv (a_0+a_2+\cdots+a_{2n-2})+(a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{2n-1})k \pmod 3
\end{equation}

Therefore, $a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{n} k^n$ is divisible by 3 for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ if and only if sum of odd term coefficients and sum of even term coefficients are both zero.

This attempt is considered to incorrect, so I retried.

---

**Second attempt:**

Let $k$ be an integer. By Fermat's little theorem,
\begin{equation}
k^3\equiv k.\pmod 3
\end{equation}
In general,
\begin{equation}
k^{2n}\equiv k^{2n-2} \equiv \cdots \equiv k^2\pmod 3
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
k^{2n+1}\equiv k^{2n-1} \equiv \cdots \equiv k\pmod 3
\end{equation}
When $a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{2n-1} k^{2n-1}$ is given,
\begin{equation}
a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{2n-1} k^{2n-1} \equiv a_0+(a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{2n-1})k+(a_2+\cdots+a_{2n-2})k^2 \pmod 3
\end{equation}
Suppose that $a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{2n-1} k^{2n-1}\equiv 0\pmod 3$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. If $k\equiv 0\pmod 3$, then $a_0\equiv 0\pmod 3$.
If $k\equiv 1\pmod 3$, then
\begin{equation}
(a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{2n-1})+(a_2+a_4+\cdots+a_{2n-2})\equiv 0.\pmod 3
\end{equation}
If $k\equiv -1\pmod 3$, then
\begin{equation}
(a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{2n-1})-(a_2+a_4+\cdots+a_{2n-2})\equiv 0.\pmod 3
\end{equation}
Thus we get
\begin{equation}
a_1+a_3+\cdots+a_{2n-1}\equiv a_2+a_4+\cdots+a_{2n-2}\equiv0\pmod 3
\end{equation}
Therefore, $a_0+a_1 k+a_2 k^2 +\cdots + a_{n} k^n$ is divisible by 3 for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $a_0\equiv 0\pmod 3$, and sum of odd term coefficients and sum of even term coefficients are both zero mod 3.

---

I have two questions:

1. Is this proof correct, or does it have something to improve?
2. Then, how to expand the proposition by selecting not only 3, but any divisor?

Comment: What if we take $k=0$?

Comment: @TZakrevskiy I see. I updated proof, adding "Let $k$ be an integer not divisible by 3." If $k$ is a multiple of 3, then proof is over.

Comment: One version of *Little Fermat* states that for *any* $k$, $k^3\equiv k\mod3$.

Comment: Just factor it!

Comment: @Bernard But how to alter $k^2$ to $1$ when only using $k^3\equiv k\pmod 3$?

Comment: @Leox I don't think that all polynomial are factored in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, For example, $x^2+2$.

Comment: It is required that the tail-coefficient ($a_0$) is divisible by $3$. Also, @choco_addicted, can't we always make such polynomials factorizable, e.g. $x^2+2\equiv x^2-1\equiv (x-1)(x+1)\mod 3$?

Comment: @vrugtehagel I see. I missed when $k$ is a multiple of 3, then $a_0$ remains mod 3. But I mentioned $x^2+2$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, not in $\mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

Comment: @choco_addicted: You will eventually have to argue according to values of $k$ mod. $3$,. This will give you three different conditions.

Comment: @Bernard I reflected your advise in second attempt. As your mention said, Three conditions, "$a_0\equiv 0\pmod 3$, "sum of even terms expect 0 is zero mod 3", and "sum of odd terms expect 0 is zero mod 3" appeared.

Comment: It's not exactly that: ‘sum of all coefficients is $0$’ if $k\equiv 1\mod3$, and ‘sum of odd coefficients congruent to sum of even coefficients’  if $k\equiv -1$.

Comment: @Bernard I updated proof so that we get expected conclusion. $a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_n$ are constants, so they are independent of $k$.

Comment: If $k\equiv -1\mod 3$, you do not have necessarily $a_0\equiv0$. This is true only if $k\equiv 0$. It simply adds to the even coefficients.

Comment: Your proof is fine but a little convaluted.  FLT says $k^3 =k \mod 3$ so $k^3 + 3k^2 +2k = k +3k^2 +2k = 3k +3k^2= 0\mod 3$.  It's that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some information that I can present to you regarding your second question.

Here, I aim to establish the condition where $P(n)$ is always divisible by $p$, where $p$ is a prime.

For any prime $p$, note the fact that for all $k \in \mathbb N$ $x \ge 1$, $k^{x+p-1} \equiv k^x \pmod p \tag{1}$.

We shall define $P(n)$ as such:
$$P(n)=\sum _{ k=0 }^{ m }{ a_{ k }n^{ k } } , a_m \neq 0$$

Note the fact that since $P(0)$ is divisible by $p$, so $a_{0}$ is divisble by $p$.

Let $Q(n)=P(n)-a_0$.

Note that by using $(1)$, we can define $R(n)$ so that $R(n) \equiv Q(n) \pmod p$

$$R(n)=\sum _{ k=1 }^{ p-1 }{ b_{ k }n^{ k } }, b_k=\sum _{ i \le m, i \equiv k \pmod p }^{ }{a_{i}}$$

Note that $R(n)$ has a degree of less than $p-1$. Also, note the fact that $R(n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has $p$ solutions modulo $p$. If every coefficient of $R(n)$ is not divisble by $p$, this is a contradiction, since $R(n) \equiv 0 \pmod p$ can not have more than $p-1$ solutions [from Lagrange's theorem](https://www.dropbox.com/s/auryzn5rlbz5lan/Lagrange_Theorem_NT.pdf?dl=0)

Thus the condition for $P(n)$ to be always divisible by $p$ is for all $b_{k}$ to be divisble by $p$ and for $a_{0} \equiv 0 \pmod p$, and this implies that your result regarding $p=3$ is correct as well.

This method can be used for square-free integers as well by dividing the cases for each $p$.

Comment: @choco_addicted Though I realize that my answer may not have been helpful, I would appreciate it if you shared your thought.

Comment: I think that your post is helpful for me, but I get confused about your notation... For example, you defined $P(n)$ as $P(n)=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k x^k$, and $R(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{p-1}b_k x^k$, but what is $x$? It seems uninformative.

Comment: @choco_addicted Oh, right! I must be stupid. Is it better now?

Comment: Yes, it is. One more question: Is $b_k=\sum_{i\le n,i\equiv k\pmod p}a_i$ correct? Shouldn't it modified to $b_k=\sum_{i\le m,i\equiv k\pmod p}a_i$?

Comment: @choco_addicted Fixed.